# Implementing the calculator program using lisp

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, lisp

I'm  implementing the calculator program using concurrent lisp programming language..Everything is working fine..but I want to print which thread is executing currently  and the particular function..however I'm able to get the list of thread using list-all-threads function...please suggest me how to do it..

following is my code with output::

```
(defvar a)     // defines a var but does not initialises it
(defvar b)
(defvar c)
(defvar d)


(write-line " Enter two numbers in binary format with prefix #b : ")  // gives newline afterwords


    (setf a (read))  

  /* SETF is a macro which uses SETQ internally, but has more possibilities. In a way it's a more general assignment operator.*/

     (setf b(read))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn (sleep 4)(setf c(+ a   b))
                (print "ADDITION in binary: ")
                (format t " ~b" c )
                (print "ADDITION in decimal: ")
                (print c)
                )
                )
                )

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 2)(setf c(- a b))
                (print "SUBTRACTION in binary: ")
                (format t " ~b" c )  
                (print "SUBTRACTION in decimal: ")
                (print c))))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 5)(setf c(* a b))
                (print "MULTIPLICATION in binary: ")
                (format t " ~b" c )
                (print "MULTIPLICATION IN DECIMAL: ")
                (print c))))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 3)(setf c(* a a))
                (print "SQUARE in binary: ")
                (format t " ~b" c )
                (print "SQUARE OF 1st NUMBER  : ")
                (print c))))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 1)(setf c(* b b b))
                (print "CUBE OF 2ND NUMBER : ")
                (print c))))    


    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 2)(setf c(sin a))
                (print "SINE OF 1ST NUMBER : ")
                (print c))))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 3)
                (setf c(tan a))
                (print "TAN OF 1ST NUMBER : ")
                (print c))))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 6)
                (setf c(cos a))
                (print "COSINE OF 1ST NUMBER : ")
                (print c))))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 2)
                (setf c(min a b))
                (print "MINIMUM NUMBER : ")
                (print c))))

    (sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(progn(sleep 1)
                (setf c(max a b))
                (print "MAXIMUM NUMBER : ")
                (print c))))

(print (sb-thread:list-all-threads))
(sleep 30 )       

(exit)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

OUTPUT:

[CGL@localhost ~]$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.2.8.14-8b3c9d0, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (load "test.lisp")
 Enter two numbers in binary format with prefix #b : 
#b1100
#b1011

(#<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {100322E8E3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {10031E4263}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {1003190D33}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {10031750D3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {1003157A73}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {10031393E3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {1003119E43}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {10030D91C3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {1003097C33}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {1003057903}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002FCE543}>) 
"CUBE OF 2ND NUMBER : " 
1331 
"MAXIMUM NUMBER : " 
12 
"SUBTRACTION in binary: "  1
"SUBTRACTION in decimal: " 
1 
"SINE OF 1ST NUMBER : " 
-0.53657293 
"MINIMUM NUMBER : " 
11 
"SQUARE in binary: "  10010000
"SQUARE OF 1st NUMBER  : " 
144 
"TAN OF 1ST NUMBER : " 
-0.6358599 
"ADDITION in binary: "  10111
"ADDITION in decimal: " 
23 
"MULTIPLICATION in binary: "  10000100
"MULTIPLICATION IN DECIMAL: " 
132 
"COSINE OF 1ST NUMBER : " 
0.84385395 [CGL@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: This can't compile because `//` and `/` etc. are not defined.  I guess that you wanted to put comments there.  Comments are introduced by one or more `;` in Common Lisp.

Comment: Oh! sorry,actually I added the comments after posting on the SO...ya the comments are given using  ;  in Lisp

Answer (score 2):

Theads can have name, use the keyword name for creating the threads like this

```
CL-USER> (defparameter empty-plus-thread  (sb-thread:make-thread #'(lambda () (sleep 10 ) (+))
                                :name "what is the sum of no things adding?") )
EMPTY-PLUS-THREAD

CL-USER> (SB-THREAD:list-all-threads)
(#<SB-THREAD:THREAD "what is the sum of no things adding?" RUNNING
    {10045998B3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1005C880B3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "auto-flush-thread" RUNNING {1005C87DF3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "swank-indentation-cache-thread" RUNNING {10050701D3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "reader-thread" RUNNING {1005070003}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "control-thread" RUNNING {100506F603}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "Swank Sentinel" RUNNING {1004DE21E3}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002C0F0A3}>)

CL-USER> (sb-thread:join-thread empty-plus-thread)

0
```

Then you also can use the variable  `sb-thread:*current-thread*` inside the thread to get or print the  name while executing.

Answer (score 2):

In SBCL the current thread object is bound to `sb-thread:*current-thread*` special variable.

```
* sb-thread:*current-thread*
#<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002AC3C43}>
```

To get or set the name of the thread object, use `sb-thread:thread-name`:

```
* (sb-thread:thread-name sb-thread:*current-thread*)
"main thread"
```

The name of the thread also could be set during the construction by passing the `&key` `name` argument:

```
(sb-thread:make-thread
    #'(lambda () (format t "Hello from thread ~A" sb-thread:*current-thread*))
    :name "my-thread-0")
```

Also you should somehow synchronize the printing calls (for example using an `sb-thread:mutex` object in a global variable), because otherwise the output could be messed up.